# How to call an external jQuery functions in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I am working on an Angular CLI Project where I need to call some jQuery functions.

I have included my js in the **angular.json** file:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "src/custom.js"
]
```

**jQuery function**:

```
function A() { alert('A'); }
function B() { alert('B'); }
```

I have imported jQuery in my component where I need to call these jQuery functions :-

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

**tsconfig.app.json** :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now, how to import **custom.js** in my component and how to call these functions A & B?

Comment: Have you tried just calling them?

Comment: can't be called directly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend installing the types for jquery if you haven't done so already:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

So you can simply use it by just importing jQuery (`jquery`) in your component/service:

```
import 'jquery';
```

---

When you have problems compiling or `build`ing your application, it can be solved by wrapping your selector in `(<any> ...)` or `(... as any)`:

```
// Use this
(<any> $('.myElement')).A();

// or this
($('.myElement') as any).A();
```

---

**Update (see comments)**

To execute code after page is ready, try implementing `AfterViewInit` to your main component (`app-root`):

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someService.someFunction();
  }
}
```

[documentation for AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit#ngAfterViewInit)

Comment: thanks @Jeffrey but where did you call, i mean how to call them. And can't we call normal jQuery functions as I have.

Comment: Is there no need to import my js file in component?

Comment: @SunilKumar The import of the js files should be done in in the angular.json file, which you did correct (so it can be globally called). You do not need to import it in your component, you only need to import jquery itself using `import 'jquery';` (make sure you install the jquery/types). To call your A/B functions, you should be able to call them using `($('.myElement') as any).A();`

Comment: ok @Jeffrey let me check but I have a doubt, could u pl explain what is "myElement" here, are you binding any html element here ?

Comment: And can I call these functions as an normal jQuery functions or do i need to convert in module format?

Comment: I thought you wanted jQuery *because* of the html element bindings, why else do you need jQuery? If your 'jQuery functions' are plain javascript, why not just convert / copy-paste them to an Angular service?

Comment: No  i know how to use jquery in angular, I have some jQuery functions which is required on multiple pages so I want to call them on demand. Is there any way so that those functions can be called automatically. Right now these are not working as u know html render after jquery imported.

Comment: I have functions which need to be called after html render (on document.ready)

Comment: You should really avoid doing that, it makes debugging very hard, because Angular may not be aware of the changes/functions you execute with jQuery. You should create a service (re-usable on every page), and bind it to the component's `ngOnInit()`, or call it when the router's `NavigationEnd` event fires.

Comment: I tried your AfterViewInit  but that is working only once , then I tried NavigationEnd that is working before view renders, @jeffrey which function/event will be useful in this case so that I get my function call after each view render. Pls modify answer.

Comment: @SunilKumar Why do you need to catch an 'after view render' of each page update? When you create a page full of `component`s, and make proper use of the router's `resolve` and `canActivate` methods, you probably don't need to wait for a view render..

Comment: I need to call a js function which will implement jquery datatables based on the class of html table, here my js function not finding table tag. Pl see this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654152/how-to-create-a-common-service-to-interate-jquery-datatable-for-all-pages-in-ang

Comment: Ah, now I better understand what the problem is. See my answer for your linked question. Let me know if that works!