# How to create a common service to integrate jQuery datatable for all pages in angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular5, angular-cli

I want to create common service to integrate jQuery datatables(with export buttons) on multiple pages.

I have installed jquery and typings for jquery. Also have included jquery in tsconfig types array.

```
"types": [
  "jquery"
]
```

Included required cdn(s) for datatable on index page.

Added an interface JQuery in typings.d.ts :

```
interface JQuery {
  <dataTable>(options?: any): any;
}
```

**Angular Service :**

```
  ApplyDatatable() {
          $(".mydataTable").dataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                bJQueryUI: true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[-1, 10, 20, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 20, 50, 100]],
                select: true,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                  {
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': ['disableSorting', 'noExport']
                  }],
                buttons: [
                  {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: [
                      //'copy',
                      {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':visible',
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':visible',
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                        }
                      }                
                ],         
                dom: 'lfBrtip',    
              }); 
}
```

**Getting error :**

jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__(...).dataTable is not a function (on browser console).

while compiling project getting the error **Property 'dataTable' does not exist on type 'JQuery'**

Answer (score 1):

When using a jQuery plugin, you should create an Angular component as a wrapper for the datatable. Then you can call the jQuery plugin after the *component* renders.

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatables',
  ...
})
export class AppDatatables implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ($(".mydataTable") as any).dataTable({
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

Component template:

```
<div class="mydataTable"></div>
```

---

Since you already asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606429/how-to-call-an-external-jquery-functions-in-angular/) how to render this for every new page(view), that problem is solved now as well, since the component will be re-added every time a new page is loaded/created.

Comment: I am getting error on browser console "TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function".

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement in jQuery way not angular way, As I require a common service so I thought to use my existing jQuery function which will implement datatables based on classname. I didn't install datatables using npm bcz if I do so dataTable functions accepts different paramenters. If you can provide me a link to create a common service for datatables with export buttons.

Comment: I know, with what I said you should be able to use a jQuery plugin. You only have to wrap it in an Angular component. The 'afterViewInit()' should be added to the datatable component, not app-component like I said earlier.

Comment: yea @JeffreyRoosendaal that will resolve my another question problem, but how to solve this "TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function"..

Comment: I've added a small code part about the component template. That's very important. Also, did you include the datatable plugin/script in your `angular.json` (or `angular-cli.json`) file?

Comment: I'm using cdn on index page bcz if I use datatable plugin in angular.json, its asking for different parameters other than this jquery function.

Comment: Hm, I don't know then.. I'm sorry. Angular and jQuery are not a good combination, so it's always hard to get it working properly. I can't help you any more I think, but good luck with your code. I can give some advice though: Please don't mix Angular with jQuery the next time, it'll save you a lot of problems :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare var $:any;
```

Write Above Statement in the service file where you're using a common function or written your datatable load function

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Copy/Paste the above script tag line, into your

> Index.html

or Any html file.. AND MAKE SURE THIS SCRIPT TAG LINE IS ON THE TOP OF ALL THE OTHER CSS/JS Including Tags In Your HTML.